# Bash: Identifying file based on part of filename

Tags: bash

I have a folder containing paired files with names that look like this:

```
PB3999_Tail_XYZ_1234.bam
PB3999_PB_YWZ_5524.bam
```

I want to pass the files into a for loop as such:

```
for input in `ls PB*_Tail_.bam`; do tumor=${input%_Tail_*.bam}; $gatk Mutect2 -I $input -I$tumor${*}; done
```

The issue is, I can't seem to get the syntax right for the tumor input. I want it to recognise the paired file by the first part of the name `PB3999_PB` while ignoring the second half of the file name `_YWZ_5524` that does not match.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Use `find` with the `iname` option

Comment: You don't need or want `ls` here; `for input in PB*_Tail_*.bam; do ...`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can pass the results from "find -inname" into a variable for downstream applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced `${*}` with `*` and added `_PB_` suffix to the prefix, to the script in the question. And, renamed variables.

```
for tailfname in PB*_Tail_*.bam; do
    pairprefix="${tailfname%_Tail_*.bam}"
    echo command with ${tailfname} ${pairprefix}_PB_*.bam
done
```

Hope this helps. The name `tumor` sounds scary. Hope the right files are paired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to fully understand what you want to do here.

If you want to extract just the first two *parts*, this should do:

```
echo "PB3999_Tail_XYZ_1234.bam" | cut -d '_' -f 1-2
```

That returns just the "PB3999_Tail" part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I'm trying to do is: 1) Identify all files in the directory named PB3999_Tail_XYZ_1234.bam; 2) Create a new variable that identifies the common element of the paired files (PB3999) and adds the identifier for the paired file to it (PB3999_PB) then; 3) Identify the full file name of the corresponding paired file and pass this in to a variable for a downstream function. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Here's a shot. Only process files where both files exists (PB and Tail):

`ls PB* | cut -d '_' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "^\s+2 .*$" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev | while read -r PB; do Tail="$(ls ${PB}_Tail_*.bam)"; echo "Tail: ${Tail}"; done`